# Set different page length for each search query

Tags: java, multithreading, marklogic, nosql

As stated in docs https://docs.marklogic.com/7.0/guide/java/intro#id_71012

> Document managers are thread safe once initially configured; no matter how many threads you have, you only need one document manager per document type.

I'd like to specify different page length for each query. But the only way I found to do that is to call the corresponding method of QueryManager. So I need to synchronize myself:

```
synchronized (queryManager) {
    queryManager.setPageLength(messagesOnPage);
    queryManager.search(queryDefinition, searchHandle, pageNo);
}
```

**Question:** Is it possible to specify page length in a different way (e.g. setting it in QueryDefinition)?

I'm using Marklogic 7.0, client-api-java 2.0.5

Thanks,
Hlib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation isn't trying to warn about managers sharing an internal state across threads.

Instead, it is attempting to clarify that you can share a single manager object across threads if you choose to so long as the manager's configuration doesn't change.

If you only use a query manager object in one thread, it's not visible to other threads, so you don't need to synchronize changes to the query manager.  If you have many threads using QueryManager, you should create a new QueryManager for each thread since you're changing the page length.

Hoping that helps,